# can two bootstrap icon class name work next to each other (class name priority)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a class name called (bi bi-clipboard), I want to when I click on it to change the class name to (bi-clipboard-check), so the problem is that it added the class name next to the other class name like this:

before clicking:

```
<i class="bi bi-clipboard" onclick="changeIcon(this)"></i>
```

After clicking:

```
<i class="bi bi-clipboard bi-clipboard-check" onclick="changeIcon(this)"></i>
```

Method:

```
function changeIcon(icon){
    icon.classList.toggle("bi-clipboard-check");
}
```

I saw somewhere else that was using fontawesome when you click on it, the class toggles by toggle() javascript method, and it works, but mine doesn't work as two class-names are next to each other.
any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: How about you toggle both classes? the one you want to add in and the one is already there?

Comment: you mean the whole class name right? I want that actually, I want to change all the class name, I want to toggle all the class name (all that is inside class attribute), but not just appending to it.

Comment: I meant two toggle statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use jQuery, you can toggle the classes separately - see JQUERY demo below

```js
$(function() {
  $(".bi").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("bi-clipboard-check");
    $(this).toggleClass("bi-clipboard");

    console.log($(this).prop('classList').value);
  });
});
```

```css
.bi {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="bi bi-clipboard"></i>
```

OR, you can just toggle the two classes separately.

**See plain JS demo below**

```js
function changeIcon(thisEl) {
  thisEl.classList.toggle("bi-clipboard-check");
  thisEl.classList.toggle("bi-clipboard");
  console.log(thisEl.classList.value);
}
```

```css
.bi {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<i class="bi bi-clipboard" onclick="changeIcon(this)"></i>
```

Comment: So It can't be done with javascript or it takes more time?

Comment: But Can I mix both JQuery and Javascript code in my (index.js) file? or I should convert all (DOM) manipulations and some others to JQuery format?!

Comment: Yes, you can use plain JS (you don't need to use JQuery) - let me update my answer

Comment: No No, I like this answer.

Comment: Don't Update it, but if you just tell me please is it ok to mix js and jquery both together?!

Comment: I'll keep both methods - gimme a moment

Comment: While you can use JS and JQuery together, it's recommended you use one or the other (since it is easier to maintain that way) - having said that; jquery is a JS library that helps with DOM manipulation and error handling.  If you are going to use it, there is little need to use plain JS.  The main reason people use plain JS is because they do not need (or want) all the functionality that JQuery offers (making their page faster to render/execute)

Comment: glad I could help; don't forget to upvote all answers you find useful (including Omar's ;) )

Comment: I have 3+ years of experience in web development, but my stackoverflow account is kind of new, I can't upvote ;( can you help me??, it needs at least 15 reputations, stackoverflow works with reputation, that is the problem.
I need reputation, if you upvote my question, I will appreciate that.

Comment: I see, all in due time then ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery,

using `contains()` method

you can check if classlist contains `bi-clipboard` and replace it with `bi-clipboard-check` and vice versa

```
function changeIcon(icon) {
    if (icon.classList.contains("bi-clipboard")) {
        icon.classList.replace("bi-clipboard", "bi-clipboard-check");
    }
    else if (icon.classList.contains("bi-clipboard-check")) {
        icon.classList.replace("bi-clipboard-check", "bi-clipboard");
    }
}
```

using `toggle()` method

```
function changeIcon(icon) {
     icon.classList.toggle("bi-clipboard-check");
     icon.classList.toggle("bi-clipboard");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check for the class to be there, you can use the `toggle` function which does that for you (don't re-invent the wheel)

Comment: Also, if a third class is present (i.e. `bi bi-clipboard text-primary` your example with `replace()` won't work (it should be contains, instead of `===`)

Comment: @blurfus you are correct, i should be using contains() instead of value, let me update it.Thank you for the remark